# how to get app directory in android nougat getFilesDir is not workimg properly

Tags: android, android-storage

I need to get the path to a library installed with the app in android. the following code works pretty well in android Lolipop. but in nougat it returns following path: "/data/user/0/com.package_name" though the actual path in which so file exists is: "/data/app/com.package_name-1/lib/arm64/lib_name.so". 
Lolipop provides this path: "/data/data/com.package_name"

```
static File getLibDirectory(Context context)
{
    File dataDir = new File(context.getFilesDir().getParent()); //returns "/data/user/0/com.package_name"

    Log.d(TAG, "dataDir: "+dataDir.getAbsolutePath() + " Existance: "+ dataDir.exists());   //exists
    boolean isExsist = false;

    if(new File(dataDir.getAbsolutePath(), "lib").exists())
        isExsist=true;
    Log.d(TAG, "libDir: "+new File(dataDir.getAbsolutePath(), "lib").getAbsolutePath() + " Existance: "+ isExsist);  //dose not exists

    return new File(dataDir.getAbsolutePath(), "lib");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> but in nougat it returns following path: "/data/user/0/com.package_name"

That is a perfectly valid value.

> though the actual path in which so file exists is: "/data/app/com.package_name-1/lib/arm64/lib_name.so".

I am not aware of any Android environment that would have such a path, though I cannot rule it out. `/data/data/com.package_name-1/lib/arm64/lib_name.so` would be possible.

The exact path varies by device, OS, and which user (among the device users) is using your app. The OS will map things appropriately, so `getFilesDir()` returns the proper value in every circumstance.